# How to convert scala.collection.Map<Object, Object> to Java's Map<Integer, Integer>?

Tags: java, scala-2.11

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> scalaIntsMapToJavaMap(scala.collection.Map<Object, Object> map) {
    return (Map<Integer, Integer>) JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(map);
}
```

When I run this Java file in sbt, I get following Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Decorators$AsJava cannot be cast to java.util.Map
        at SomeClass.scalaIntsMapToJavaMap(SomeClass.java:92)
        at SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:57)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Comment: What Java file do you run? You've listed only one function. Please show a complete example

Answer (score 1):

After googling a bit I found this:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> scalaIntsMapToJavaMap(scala.collection.Map<Object, Object> map) {
  return (Map<Integer, Integer>) JavaConverters$.MODULE$.mapAsJavaMapConverter(map);
}
```

However, more elegant solution is to expose Java version of your method in Scala code. From scala code you can do this using:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val map: Map[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)
def getMap(): java.collection.Map[Integer, Integer] = {
  map.asJava()
}
```